# Proper way of conditional styling

Tags: css, polymer, styling

Is this proper way of conditional styling of an element? Works great on Chrome, sadly not on other browsers but it seems to me that it is super easy and great way of doing it.

```
<template if="{{data.Reply}}">
        <style>
            :host {
                background: #1ba1e2;
                right: 100px;
            }
        </style>

    </template>
    <template if="{{!data.Reply}}">
        <style>
            :host {
                background: #33C03A;
                left: 100px;
            }
        </style>
    </template>

<style>
        :host {
            ....
        }
</style>
```

Comment: it would be better to have a single style outside the conditional statements and have classes for each case. in the conditional template apply the proper class on the elements that you want styled.

Comment: Yes of course, but i don't think it is possible to add class to :host from within the element.